# Angular 2 service variables giving console errors when referenced in template

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to display data that is retrieved from a service, and display it in my HTML. My method works, but it outputs errors in the console, and I'm not sure how to resolve them.

Here is how my app works:

**app.component.ts**

```
// initialize the variable that will store the returned message object
messages: any;

// call the service
this.TaskService.getMessages()
  .subscribe(response => {
     // response will be an object with two key:value pairs inside
     this.messages = response;
  });
```

And how I display it in my **html**:

```
<div>
   <span class="hello">{{messages.hello}}</span>
   <span class="goodbye">{{messages.goodbye}}</span>
</div>
```

Whenever I run this, the html values are displayed properly, but I receive the following errors in my console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'goodbye' of undefined

My theory to why this happens is because the service isn't finished retrieving the values by the time the template tries to load them. However, I'm not sure how to resolve it, if this is the case.

(aside from creating component level variables that initialize 'hello' and 'goodbye', then change their values when the service is done with its call, but that seems inefficient)

How can I display values retrieve from my service, and display them in my HTML without having console errors?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error arises because when the template is rendered, the values of `messages` is still undefined yet, due to it being asynchronously assigned. There are a few ways to solve this problem:

#### 1. Elvis Operator

Angular supports the usage of [Elvis Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) in binding the html template.

```
<div>
   <span class="hello">{{messages?.hello}}</span>
   <span class="goodbye">{{messages?.goodbye}}</span>
</div>
```

*Note that you can only use the elvis operator in the html template, and not in the Typescript or JavaScript, as they are not supported yet.*

#### 2. Use `*ngIf`

To prevent the template to do the binding with any objects that is undefined, simply remove the DOM, and that is exactly what `*ngIf` does:

```
<div *ngIf="messages !== undefined">
   <span class="hello">{{messages.hello}}</span>
   <span class="goodbye">{{messages.goodbye}}</span>
</div>
```

or simply if you trust in truthiness of the object:

```
<div *ngIf="messages">
   <span class="hello">{{messages.hello}}</span>
   <span class="goodbye">{{messages.goodbye}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?.` to protect against cases where `messages` is null:

```
<div>
   <span class="hello">{{messages?.hello}}</span>
   <span class="goodbye">{{messages?.goodbye}}</span>
</div>
```